# Можно ли обратиться из контроллера к нескольким моделям?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mvc

Начинаю изучать `Ruby on Rails`, с `MVC` еще не работала, и немного запуталась. В принципе вопрос, я думаю, относится не только к `Ruby on Rails`.

Делаю интернет-магазин, такой вопрос: если мне нужно вывести на одной странице, например, список пользователей и список товаров, правильно ли будет из одного контроллера, который соответствует этой странице, обращаться и к модели `"Пользователь"`, и к модели `"Товар"`? На практике это осуществить можно, все работает, но интересует, не нарушаю ли я какие-то правила построения `MVC`?

Подскажите, пожалуйста, если правильно делать по-другому. Не должна ли одна модель соответствовать одному контроллеру?

Comment: Вообще такое практикуется и не возбраняется. В некоторых случаях имеет смысл использовать сервисные объекты. Чтобы получить конкретные рекомендации, лучше добавить в вопрос код контроллера и код представлений.

Comment: А как эти два списка связаны между собой, что демонстрируются на одной странице?

Answer (score 1):

Этим вы "правила" MVC никак не нарушаете, и я не особо представляю, как в некоторых ситуациях можно сделать иначе. Правила вы нарушете, если начнете обращться к моделям из вьюхи например.